# Are the lists from "BondList" and EdgeList for a molecule guaranteed to be aligned?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, chemistry

Consider the following:

```
ClearAll[mol1, bondList, edgeList];
mol1 = Molecule["COc1cc(C2Oc3cc(C4Oc5cc(O)cc(O)c5C(=O)C4O)ccc3OC2CO)ccc1O"];
bondList = MoleculeValue[mol1, "BondList"];
edgeList = mol1 // (MoleculeGraph /* EdgeList);
{bondList, edgeList} // (
    Transpose /*
    Cases[Except[{Bond[{s_, t_}, _], UndirectedEdge[s_, t_]}]]
)

(* {} *)
```

This always appears to work. But is it something that is *guaranteed* by Mathematica? In other words, is it safe to assume this alignment of ordering in other algorithms?

Comment: the function `MoleculeGraph` calls ``Chemistry`Private`MoleculeGraphDump`iMoleculeGraph`` which, in turn, constructs the edge list from the `BondList`. So they are _aligned_ by construction. Depending on the value of the option `Method` we might have multi edges. If the option value is `Automatic|SimpleGraph|Simplegraph`  bond type (Single, Double, Triple,Auromatic)  is attached as a property to the edge, if it is `MultiGraph` or `Multigraph` multi edges are constructed for `Double` and `Triple` and a single edge for `Single` and `Auromatic`.

Comment: @kglr if you write your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two lists are *aligned* by construction.

The function `MoleculeGraph` calls `` Chemistry`Private`MoleculeGraphDump`iMoleculeGraph `` which, in turn, constructs the edge list from the `BondList`.

Depending on the value of the option `Method` we might have multi edges. If the option value is `Automatic|"SimpleGraph"|"Simplegraph"` bond type (`"Single"`, `"Double"`, `"Triple"` or `"Aromatic"`) is attached as the `Property` `"BondOrder"` to the edge; if it is `"MultiGraph"` or `"Multigraph"` multi edges are constructed for `"Double"` and `"Triple"` and a single edge for `"Single"` and `"Aromatic"` bond types.